# Powershell: How to show output onscreen and output to file?

Tags: powershell

Hope you can help. Very new to PS, so please be patient :)

I have a problem with the script below. If I put the Out-File command on line 6, the results are printed in the powershell screen, but the txt file is blank. If I put the Out-File command at the end of Line 3, the text file is populated, but it doesn't output the results in the powershell window.
I'd like it to do both.
Frustrating :(

```
import-module activedirectory
$username = Read-Host 'Please enter Username!'
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $username | Get-ADGroup -Properties * | select name, description | Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize
$wsh = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$wsh.Popup("List has been saved to C:\Group_List.txt")
Out-File C:\Group_List.txt
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Comment: Do you want it to show up in the pop up? Maybe assign your query a variable and then just work with it that way? or if you want it to show up in the terminal you can do write-host

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Tee-Object` (inspired by the classic `tee` unix command-line tool) to fork an input stream into a variable or to a file on disk! If you want to write the formatted table to file as-is, simply tack it onto the end of the pipeline expression that outputs to the screen (you can skip the `select` command, `Format-Table` also takes a property list)

```bsh
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $username | Get-ADGroup -Properties description | Format-Table -Property name,description -Wrap -AutoSize | Tee-Object -FilePath C:\Group_List.txt
```

If the output file is intended for later consumption by another computer/program, I would change strategies and export to a CSV file instead. To capture the data and output to both, we can assign the results of the initial query to a variable and then output twice in separate statements:

```
$groupsWithDescription = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $username |Get-ADGroup -Properties description |Select-Object Name,Description

# Output to screen, format as table
$groupData |Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize 

# Output to file, export data as CSV
$groupData |Export-Csv -Path C:\Group_List.txt -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I owe you a beer Mathias! Works beautifully, thank you!

Comment: @Phill Great to hear! While my answer provides a solution to the problem as described, depending on purpose you might want to review the advice and adopt the approach in [Theo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63632604/712649)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you do not capture the results from the `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` cmdlet anywhere and just send it out to screen using `Format-Table`.

Secondly, the output does not show the user that is a member of these groups, so if you are typing another user, the file would not reveal for which user these groups are valid..

Finally, insert a test to check if the inputted username actually is an existing user.

I would go for outputting a CSV file you can simply open in Excel. Something like this:

```
Import-Module activedirectory

$outFile  = 'C:\Group_List.csv'
$username = Read-Host 'Please enter Username!'

# do some error checking to see if this is an existing user
$user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$username'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($user) {
    $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user.DistinguishedName | 
              Get-ADGroup -Properties Description | ForEach-Object {
                # output an object with properties you need
                [PsCustomObject]@{
                    User        = $username
                    Group       = $_.Name
                    Description = $_.Description
                }
            }

    # show on screen
    $groups | Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize

    # write to CSV file
    $groups | Export-Csv -Path $outFile -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation

    $wsh = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
    $wsh.Popup("List has been saved to $outFile")

    # clean up COM object after use
    $null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wsh)
    [System.GC]::Collect()
    [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
}
else {
    Write-Warning "User $username does not exist.."
}
```

Comment: Very elegant. I like this very much. Thank you Theo!

Answer (score -1):

1. Try adding the outfile command after your "Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership".
   Should look something like this.

   ```
   Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $username | Get-ADGroup -Properties * | select name, description | Format-Table -Wrap -AutoSize| Out-File -FilePath $path
   ```
2. Using  export-csv

   ```
   `$result | export-csv -Path $csvFileName -NoTypeInformation`
   ```